# VBA Outlook automatically mark all emails in a folder as read

Tags: vba, outlook

I have created a rule in my Outlook. This rule exports some of my emails to a folder called "Others", if their subjects contain a specific word. Through VBA, I want to automatically mark all emails in the folder "Others" as read, either when I start outlook or when I receive the emails that need to go to the folder "Others".

Comment: Can't the rule handle it?

Comment: Thanks for the codes. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your macro security settings are set correctly:

for <kbd>**Outlook 2010**</kbd> and up: File, Options, Trust Center, Trust Center Settings, Macro Security otherwise, you'll need to use selfcert.exe to sign your macros to test them which I highly recommended

Email will be marked read when it is moved to a subfolder ("Others") of the inbox.

Place the code in ThisOutlookSession module, you must restart Outlook.

Tested on <kbd>**Outlook 2010**</kbd>

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

  Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Folder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  '// change the folder if need here
  Set Folder = olFolder.Folders("Others")
  Set Items = Folder.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  Item.UnRead = False
  Item.Save
End Sub
```